# Best LaTeX practices for writing "N objects", and so on

Tags: math-mode, best-practices

Q1: If I want to write in a mathematical article, the following sentence:

```
Consider N real numbers $x_i$...
```

Q2: Is it better practice to write "`$N$`" or simply "`N`"? Similarly, if one is writing:

```
Let $M$ be a 3-dimensional manifold.
```

Do I write "`$3$-dimensional`", or "`3-dimensional`"?

Q3: when does one use `\cdots`, and when does one use `\ldots`? For instance, if I were to write "`x_1,...,x_n`", is it better to write "`$x_1,\ldots,x_n$`" or "`$x_1,\cdots,x_n$`"?

These are 3 questions that always confused me. I would appreciate someone's help. Is there an online document that may tackle similar issues perhaps (including how to break long words)? Could someone please provide a link to that document?

Comment: `Consider $N$ real numbers $x_i$` (`N` is a math variable), `Let $M$ be a 3-dimensional manifold` (`3` is part of a word and has nothing to do with math), `x_1, \dots, x_n` (with `mathtools` loaded `\dots` is intelligent; in any case in that place you should go with `\ldots`, but as I say, `\dots` is enough).

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know about \dots in particular! Thank you. I am also reading a document by the AMS on best practices, which is also very helpful.

Comment: And don't forget the non-breaking space: `Consider $N$~real numbers…`, in case these words are typeset at the end of a line. (Not in this peculiar case of course, but who knows, after a copy-paste…)

Comment: @Manuel I would definitely write `$3$-dimensional` if it is to be a numeral, cf. `$n$-dimensional`, but one might also write `three-dimensional`

Comment: Thank you @FranckPastor. This is helpful too, though I deal with it the lazy way, by not writing $~$ here, and dealing with "bad" cases, as they occur. I also have issues with some words at the end of lines going over the margins, and not being properly hyphenated by LaTeX. But this is another question, and so I guess should be in another post (though I am sure I will find an existing post dealing with this issue!).

Comment: Thank you Prof. @AndrewSwann, father of the Swann bundle. This is how I usually write it too actually: $3$-dimensional.

Comment: @AndrewSwann You are right, it's not an absolute as I said. There could be a case in which yes it could be typeset with math mode. But there are also cases in which that three should be text mode in my opinion. If you are dealing with `1-dimensional`, `2-dimensional`, `3-dimensional` and `n-dimensional` in the same document, then yes, all of them in math mode.